# Regex pattern to remove XML tag symbol withing the line

Tags: regex, beautifulsoup

I am using beatifulsoup in python to work with an XML output.
However my code fails once I face a line that have "" within a line.
I attempted to use a regex to remove the "<>" and leave only "*TEXT*".
For example:

```
<col><Test> <This is a test, please remove></col>
```

Using regex I want to leave it as follow:

```
<col>Test This is a test, please remove</col>
```

As mentioned my regex didnt match well and I am not able to remove the tags symbols.
My closest regex was the following but is not matching well.

```
(?!^<col>|<\/col>$)(?!^)<|>(?!$)
```

Any help will be more than welcome.
Thx!

Comment: Take a look at beautifulsoup's [get_text()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) and [unwrap()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap) functions to do this without regex. Expression-wise, I'd look for a non-col tag followed by a closing col tag on the same line. Something like `<((?!col\b)[^<>]+)>(?=[^\r\n]*</col>)` and replace by the first captured group `\1`.

Comment: Thanks! I will check on Beautiful soup functions and see if I can make it.

Comment: Note that beautifulsoup will probably only understand other tags to be inside <col></col> when they are better formed than in your example. If you can give a couple of representative examples of the data you're working with, we could give more specific help.